# Rename a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to rename/drop, a Mongo collection where I have inadvertently put a . (dot) at the end of the DB collection name so the collection name looks like this:

collectionName.

I'm not able to find a way to use the collection name including the dot to either drop or rename the collection without getting an error back.

Any suggestions whether this is possible.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the link. It gave me the clues needed to drop the collection.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/)

```
> use mytestdb
> db.orders.renameCollection( "orders2015" )
```

Comment: In general, yes a direct `renameCollection` is what would be needed here. But did you try this using the specifics mentioned in this question (a collection with a trailing `.` character)? The collection needs to be retrieved differently, as shown the answer linked by @ray in the comments